# I am looking for short way to have nested list of numbers in python?

Tags: python

I am looking for a short way to have nested list of numbers in python
like below

```
nestedList = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
 [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
 [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]]
```

my working code:

```
outlist=[]
n1,n2=1,8
for i in range(6):
    inlist=[]
    for j in range(n1,n2):
        inlist.append(j)
    n1,n2 = n2, n2+7
    outlist.append(inlist)
print(outlist)
```

is there way to reduce the number of lines (pythonic way)?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Same as nestedList, all I want is reduced codes (pythonic way)

Comment: How about this - `[list(range(i,i+7)) for i in range(1,42,7)]`

Comment: @ Vaebhav 42 should be 43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R, C = 6, 7

nestedList = [[row * C + col + 1 for col in range(C)] for row in range(R)]

print(nestedList)
```

Comment: This solution is ideal if it's invoked as `R rows (6) and C columns (7)` since that can be generalised to: `[[row * C + col + 1 for col in range(C)] for row in range(R)]`. The [other ideal solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380568/1431750).

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that. Edited the answer.

Comment: Usually best to keep the specific answer (which you had) and then add the generalised version for ease of understand (esp if the poster is a beginner to the topic).

Answer (score 2):

You can write this in just one single line:

```
outlist = [list(range(x, x + 7)) for x in range(1, 43, 7)]
```

Comment: 42 should be 43

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both will give the same result as the range is at a rate of every 7.

Comment: Indeed, it does not matter, but sake of clarity I'll still edit my answer and write 43 as this is 1 + 6*7. And it makes it more explicit that the last number in the output should be 42. Thanks for spotting that, @Pavn

Comment: This solution is ideal if it's invoked as `starting num S (1), ending num E (42) and items per row/list P (7)` since that can be generalised to: `[list(range(x, x + P)) for x in range(S, E, P)]`. Also, since it involves less math to generate the values, it's simple to read. The [other ideal solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380572/1431750).

Answer (score 2):

You can give this to generate the list.

```
nested_list = [[j+i*7 for j in range(1,8)] for i in range (6)]
print (nested_list)
```

Output will be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]]
```

Comment: Thanks Joe Ferndz only 1 change to match my result. for i in range (7), 7 needs to be 6, can u edit this(for others)?

Answer (score 1):

Given the desired format, here's one way using list comprehension. This is generalized so you can change the number of elements for each inner list.

```
n1 = 7
nestedList = [list(range(n1*i + 1, n1*i + (n1+1))) for i in range(6)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
 [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
 [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]]
```